# Error occurring during video streaming on Ubuntu 16.04 Server using python 2.7.12

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp, codec, hevc

I am trying to run the python code for IP camera streaming using OpenCV in continuous streaming but sometimes I have to face mentioned below error

```
[hevc @ 0x2721ca0] The cu_qp_delta 118 is outside the valid range [-26, 25].
```

I am using a headless server with Ubuntu 16.04 available and python 2.7.12

mentioned below are my OpenCV specification available in server

```
dpkg -l | grep libopencv
ii  libopencv-calib3d2.4v5:amd64               2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision Camera Calibration library
ii  libopencv-contrib2.4v5:amd64               2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision contrib library
ii  libopencv-core2.4v5:amd64                  2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision core library
ii  libopencv-features2d2.4v5:amd64            2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision Feature Detection and Descriptor Extraction library
ii  libopencv-flann2.4v5:amd64                 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional spaces library
ii  libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64               2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision High-level GUI and Media I/O library
ii  libopencv-imgproc2.4v5:amd64               2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision Image Processing library
ii  libopencv-legacy2.4v5:amd64                2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision legacy library
ii  libopencv-ml2.4v5:amd64                    2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision Machine Learning library
ii  libopencv-objdetect2.4v5:amd64             2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision Object Detection library
ii  libopencv-photo2.4v5:amd64                 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision computational photography library
ii  libopencv-video2.4v5:amd64                 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1                    amd64        computer vision Video analysis library
```

Using mentioned below code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import imutils

def main():
    counter = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
    cap.open("rtsp://username:password IP : port/Streaming/Channels/101")

    while True:
        if cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            roi1 = frame[100:955, 250:1770]
            frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=720)
            roi1 = imutils.resize(roi1, width=720)    
            cv2.imshow('roi1', roi1)
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
            break

main()
```

suggestions will be really helpful.